# What is the difference about GetKeyState and GetAsyncKeyState?

Tags: c++, windows

From **MSDN** , I have learned that `GetKeyState` is associated with message queue of current thread.

Then I created two sample applications : `KeyPresser` and `BackChecker`.

I press a key in `KeyPresser` , in this application , I am using **GetKeyState/GetAsyncKeyState/GetKeyboardState** to retrieve the pressed key state , and they tell me that key is pressing down.

Then I send(or post) a message form `KeyPresser` to `BackChecker` , to notify `BackChecker` to check the key state in it's thread .

I get same result from `BackChecker` indicate that key is pressed. But I think **GetKeyState/GetKeyboardState** should return **zero** because the key is pressed in thread of `KeyPresser` , which is not associated with thread of `BackChecker`.

**Why?**

Comment: Did you use `GetKeyState()` or `GetAsyncKeyState()`? Because the latter hits the hardware directly, whereas the former is designed to be used from a input message handler, and is driven by the message queue.

Comment: I know the difference in MSDN , but my exam got same result from them .

Answer (score 4):

Keyboard input on Windows is buffered.  It ensures the user can keep typing, even if the program is temporarily unresponsive.  It always is, to some degree, no loss of keystrokes that way.  They are added to the message queue, the program's message loop retrieves them with GetMessage() later.

Along with the keystroke, it also stores the state of all the other keys.  To ensure that, when the message is eventually retrieved, you can reliable tell what other keys were down.  Very important for the modifier keys for example.  A shortcut keystroke like Ctrl+A would not work reliably otherwise.

So you generally *always* use GetKeyState(), you get the state of the keys as they were recorded originally.  Or GetKeyboardState(), you get the whole enchilada.  Using GetAsyncKeyState() is much less common, it doesn't rely on the buffered state, only needed if the app has very unusual message handling.  Might be appropriate in a game perhaps.

Comment: Usually buffered at the keyboard (in addition to the OS)

Comment: No, the keyboard does not buffer.  The BIOS used to buffer back in the DOS days, 8 keystrokes.  My very first TSR project, increasing that size :)  Not relevant anymore on Windows.